# Proof of $-\nabla\times\omega = \nabla^2 U$

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

What is a proof for
$$
-\nabla\times\omega = \nabla^2 U
$$
in the scope of fluid mechanics? I'm learning vector calculus for my project and stuck on this seemingly simple proof problem. Detailed answer with underlying concepts would be the most useful, as I want to have a clear understanding of what is happening and what concepts do I need to use to prove the expression. I suppose that I need to use the Levi Civita and Kronecker delta to get a proof.

Comment: Any specification regarding $\vec{\omega}$ and $\vec{U}$ ?

Comment: No, there is no specification, only mention that they are simple tensors.

Comment: What is $\vec{U}$? Probably the velocity field, but you need to specify what physical quantities $\vec{\omega}$ and $\vec{U}$ represent.

Comment: You need to elaborate on the connection between $\omega$ and $U$. My guess would be that $U$ is velocity and $\omega$ is vorticity but I am not that familiar with fluids.

Comment: I have modified the expression. There are no specifications, just the task is to prove the above expression. It was only mentioned that these values are tensors.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, if $\omega$ is an arbitrary vector field and $U$ is some other arbitrary vector field then this equality can fail in spectacular fashion. There must be some given connection here, which probably comes from the physics, not from mathematics.

Comment: Is there a solution if we assume that the expression is $-\nabla\times\omega = \nabla^2 \omega$ or $-\nabla\times U = \nabla^2 U$ ?

Comment: Or let's assume that $\vec{\omega}$ is a vorticity and $vec{U}$ is a velocity. Then we could expand the expression to the following: $-\nabla\times(\nabla\cdot\vec{U}) = \nabla^2 \vec{U}$. Correct? How do I proceed from this point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only holds in an incompressible flow.

Vorticity is defined by

$$\mathbb{\omega} = \nabla \times \mathbb{u}.$$

We have the vector identity

$$\nabla \times\mathbb{\omega} = \nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbb{u} = \nabla(\nabla \cdot \mathbb{u})- \nabla^2 \mathbb{u}.$$

This is derived as follows using Cartesian coordinates:

$$\begin{align}(\nabla \times \mathbb{\omega})_i &= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j [\epsilon_{klm}\partial_lu_m] \\ &= \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}\partial_j\partial_lu_m \\ &= \epsilon_{kij}\epsilon_{klm}\partial_j\partial_lu_m \\ &= (\delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl})\partial_j\partial_lu_m \\ &= \partial_i\partial_ju_j - \partial_j\partial_ju_i \end{align} $$

In an *incompressible* flow the velocity field is solenoidal to ensure conservation of mass,

$$\nabla \cdot \mathbb{u} = 0,$$

and your desired result follows.

Comment: So, $\epsilon^{ijk}\epsilon^{klm}\partial_k\partial_lu_m = \nabla^2 u$ ? Correct?

Comment: No its $\nabla(\nabla \cdot u) - \nabla^2 u$.  You can't get the desired result without the condition that divergence of $u$ is 0 -- which comes from physics.

Comment: This is a well known identity -- look up curl of curl.  Or we can continue the derivation using the relationship between Levi Civita and Kroneckar delta.

Comment: Alright, I will try to continue the derivation using the relationship between Levi Civita and Kroneckar delta on my own first. Do you think you could expand your answer with it? I will get peek if I get stuck again.

Comment: I continued the derivation above.